# Break a listView into categories

Tags: android, listview, categories

In my application I have a listView with more than 200 items which are retrieved from a database using a database helper class. This listView needs to be split into 10 different categories. Thus, I am adding another (parent) view. What is the best way to achieve that? The best in the sense of requiring the least possible code refactoring.

```
 public class CompaniesList extends ListActivity {

        protected EditText searchText;
        protected SQLiteDatabase db;
        protected Cursor cursor;
        protected ListAdapter adapter;


        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            searchText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchText);
            db = (new DatabaseHelper(this)).getWritableDatabase();
        }


        public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, CompanyDetails.class);
            Cursor cursor = (Cursor) adapter.getItem(position);
            intent.putExtra("EMPLOYEE_ID",
                    cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id")));
            startActivity(intent);
        }


        public void search(View view) {
            // || is the concatenation operation in SQLite
            cursor = db
                    .rawQuery(
                            "SELECT _id, name, address FROM employee WHERE employee.name LIKE ?",
                            new String[] { "%" + searchText.getText().toString()
                                    + "%" });
            adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.company_list_item,
                    cursor, new String[] { "name", "address" }, new int[] {
                            R.id.name, R.id.address }, 0);
            setListAdapter(adapter);
        }

        class CompanyCategoryAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CompaniesList> {

private LayoutInflater inflator;

    static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView text;
        public ImageView image;
    }
            private static final int ROW_TYPE_AAA = 0;
            private static final int ROW_TYPE_BBB = 1;
            private static final int ROW_TYPE_CCC = 2;
            private static final int ROW_TYPE_DDD = 3;
            private static final int ROW_TYPE_EEE = 4;
            private static final int ROW_TYPE_FFF = 5;
            private static final int ROW_TYPE_GGG = 6;
            private static final int ROW_TYPE_HHH = 7;
            private static final int ROW_TYPE_III = 8;
            private static final int ROW_TYPE_JJJ = 9;
            private static final int ROW_TYPE_KKK = 10;
            private static final int ROW_TYPE_LLL = 11;
            private static final int ROW_TYPE_MMM = 12;
            private static final int ROW_TYPE_NNN = 13;

            CompanyCategoryAdapter() {
                super(CompaniesList.this, R.layout.main, companies);
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View row = convertView;
                Companies viewHolder;

                if (row == null) {
                    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                    switch (getItemViewType(position)) {
                    case ROW_TYPE_AAA:
                        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_aaa, null);
                        break;
                    case ROW_TYPE_BBB:
                        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_bbb, null);
                        break;
                    case ROW_TYPE_CCC:
                        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_ccc, null);
                        break;
                    case ROW_TYPE_DDD:
                        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_ddd, null);
                        break;
                    case ROW_TYPE_EEE:
                        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_eee, null);
                        break;
                    case ROW_TYPE_FFF:
                        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_fff, null);
                        break;
                    case ROW_TYPE_GGG:
                        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_ggg, null);
                        break;
                    case ROW_TYPE_HHH:
                        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_hhh, null);
                        break;
                    case ROW_TYPE_III:
                        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_iii, null);
                        break;
                    case ROW_TYPE_JJJ:
                        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_jjj, null);
                        break;
                    case ROW_TYPE_KKK:
                        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_kkk, null);
                        break;
                    case ROW_TYPE_LLL:
                        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_lll, null);
                        break;
                    case ROW_TYPE_MMM:
                        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_mmm, null);
                        break;
                    case ROW_TYPE_NNN:
                        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_nnn, null);
                        break;
                    default:
                        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, null);
                        break;
                    }

                    viewHolder = new CompanyHolder(row);
                    row.setTag(viewHolder);
                } else {
                    viewHolder = (CompanyHolder) row.getTag();
                }

                viewHolder.populateFrom(companies.get(position));

                return row;
            }

            @Override
            public int getViewTypeCount() {
                return 14;
            }

            @Override
            public int getItemViewType(int position) {
                Cursor cursor = (Cursor) adapter.getItem(position);
                String type = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("department"));
                if (type.equals("aaa") == true) {
                    return ROW_TYPE_AAA;
                } else if (type.equals("bbb") == true) {
                    return ROW_TYPE_BBB;
                } else if (type.equals("ccc") == true) {
                    return ROW_TYPE_CCC;
                } else if (type.equals("ddd") == true) {
                    return ROW_TYPE_DDD;
                } else if (type.equals("eee") == true) {
                    return ROW_TYPE_EEE;
                } else if (type.equals("fff") == true) {
                    return ROW_TYPE_FFF;
                } else if (type.equals("ggg") == true)  {
                    return ROW_TYPE_GGG;
                } else if (type.equals("hhh") == true)  {
                    return ROW_TYPE_HHH;
                } else if (type.equals("iii") == true)  {
                    return ROW_TYPE_III;
                } else if (type.equals("jjj") == true)  {
                    return ROW_TYPE_JJJ;
                } else if (type.equals("kkk") == true)  {
                    return ROW_TYPE_KKK;
                } else if (type.equals("lll") == true)  {
                    return ROW_TYPE_LLL;
                } else if (type.equals("mmm") == true)  {
                    return ROW_TYPE_MMM;
                } else {
                    return ROW_TYPE_NNN;
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: why not you use expandable list view

Comment: I don't know that an ExpandableListView is the best approach considering you would be expanding a custom list approach into the ListView. I would either create a ListFragment with just the categories that when clicked takes the user to a new ListFragment showing that categories items or offer a spinner in the actionbar that allow the user to choose a category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could override getViewTypeCount() and getItemViewType

```
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 10;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return getItem(position).getType(); // or whatever is your criteria for distinguish the Types
}
```

whit those Methods you can make different Layouts for each Type in your `getView(..)` without worry about recycled Views.

Comment: I added the code for my default activity which is where I want to display all the categories. When I follow your advice, do I need to add an inner class which extends arrayAdapter and implements the two methods you mentioned and then call those methods inside my onCreate() method?

Comment: Yes you need an CustomAdapter that implements those 2 Methods, plus you need to implement the getView Method of the Adapter, thats the Method that generate the different Layouts for your Items. You dont need to call those Methods in your onCreate, the System takes care for you.